# JS array value binding to existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible?
I'm trying to do the following thing:

```
var foo = 'foo';
var bar = 'bar';

var x;
var y;

var array1 = [x, [foo, y]];
var array2 = [x, [foo, bar], [foo, y]];

console.log(array1[0]); //undefined
console.log(array1[1][1]); //undefined

console.log(array2[0]); //undefined
console.log(array2[2][1]); //undefined

array1[0] = 'working';
array2[0] = 'working';

y = 'hello';

console.log(array1[0]); //working
console.log(array1[1][1]); //undefined

console.log(array2[0]); //working
console.log(array2[2][1]); //undefined
```

Although it's obvious to define value when you know where the binding value exist ,`x` in this case, it's hard to bind a value to values with unknown location, `y` in this case.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: It's not really obvious what you're trying to do, but you should probably read up on how variables are passed in javascript, and then read up on how pass-by-value works ?

Comment: Well, I know how variables are passed in JS. I don't agree what I'm trying to do is obvious. That is why you said `you should probably read up on how variables are passed in javascript`

Comment: I didn't say it was obvious, I said it was ***not*** obvious as there is no explanation of either the code or the problem ?

Comment: I was trying to say  I don't agree what I'm trying to do is NOT obvious. and in such a obvious question, I always observe such an unproductive commenters tends to gather because the topic IS easy. I've got an answer from who understood the issue, anyway.

Comment: And to whom vote to close this Question. As you see there's a valid answer and 3 upvotes instantly. Which indicates a fact this Q&A is understandable and useful information to some people for sure. I don't  like unproductive `Topic Closer` around here since they basically destroy value of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is some kind of wrapper:

```
var x = {};
var y = {};

var array = [x, [foo, y]];

console.log(array[0].value); // undefined
console.log(array[1][1].value); // undefined

x.value = "hello";
y.value = "goodbye";

console.log(array[0].value); // hello
console.log(array[1][1].value); // goodbye
```

Comment: Thanks Russell Zahniser. This seems to be a way. Appreciated.